# MySQL complex join query

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables
   1)master_category

```
 cat_id             cat_name
------------------------------
   1                   Mobiles
   2                   Motorola
   3                   Microsoft
   4                   Mobile Accessories
   5                   Samsung
   6                   Sony
   7                   Samsung Accessories
   8                   Galaxy S6
   9                   Laptops
   10                  HP
   11                  Sony Vaio
   12                  Dell
   13                  Dell Accessories
  --------------------------------------------
```

2)category_group ( In this table grouping category master datas -  **main_group** and **Sub_group** are **cat_ids** from **master_category** table

```
   id        Main_group        Sub_group
 -----------------------------------------------------
   1             1                 2
   2             1                 3
   3             1                 4
   4             1                 5
   5             1                 6
   6             4                 7
   7             5                 8
   8             9                 10
   9             9                 11
   10            9                 12
   11            12                13
 ---------------------------------------------
```

in **category_group** category Mobile have sub categories like motoroal,microsoft,samsung,mobile accessories   and mobile acessories have sub category samsung accessories, Also samsung have sub groups galaxy s6

Laptops are also grouped like that

when i search **mobiles** i need to write a query to get a result as follows

```
 cat_id              cat_name
-------------------------------
   2                    Motorola 
   3                    Microsoft
   4                    Mobile Accessories
   5                    Samsung
   6                    Sony
   7                    Samsung Accessories
   8                    galaxy s6
 ---------------------------------------------
```

when i search **Laptops** i need to get a result as follows

```
   cat_id                cat_name
 ----------------------------------
     10                     HP
     11                     Sony Vaio
     12                     Dell
     13                     Dell Accessories
---------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Nothing terribly complex about this.  It's a bit unusual to have manufacturers and product categories in the same table though.  Was just composing the same answer as KA_lin, but he beat me to it.

Comment: Where is the SQL you have already tried that isn't working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already marked I believe that is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/192462/4421474

But since this particular question has particular dataset, here is my approach (not universal but working)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2787a/1

```
SELECT names.*
FROM master_category mc
LEFT JOIN category_group sc #level1
ON sc.main_group = mc.cat_id
LEFT JOIN category_group sc2 #level2
ON sc2.main_group = sc.sub_group
LEFT JOIN master_category names
ON sc.sub_group = names.cat_id
  OR sc2.sub_group = names.cat_id
where mc.cat_name = 'Mobiles'
order by names.cat_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not that complex, you have to join with an alias otherwise you will get something like: '*Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous*' (hope I don`t have a typo):

```
select products.id,products.cat_name from category_group 
join master_category as category on master_category.cat_id=category.Main_group
join master_category as products on master_category.cat_id=products.Sub_group
where category.cat_name='Mobiles'
```

Also take a look at this: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: it doesn't provide result   
             `7             Samsung Accessories`
             `8            galaxy s6`